# Running Hudson without access to a network

Tags: networking, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I'm trying to run Hudson as a stand alone process on a laptop I will be using to give a demonstration on. The problem is that in the place I will be doing my demo, I won't have access to any network and I am therefore trying to run Hudson while the laptop is diconnected from all networks.

The problem I'm having is that when I explode the .war file with the command:

```
java -jar hudson.war
```

I get:

```
WARNING: UDP Handling Problem
```

Which means that Hudson cannot find a socket (because I'm not connected to any network).

I've tried running Hudson with the parameters:

```
java -jar hudson.war --httpPort=9999 httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1
```

But this still gives me the UDP Handling problem.

Does anyone know a way I can work around this to get my demo up and running?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a Windows machine, make sure to switch off your firewall or add a rule to allow the java process to open a socket. Opening a socket doesn't necessarily mean that you need to be connected to a network of any kind. It will open a server socket on your machine which will accept connections.

Comment: Yes it is a Windows machine, although I've already turned off my firewall, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open port 9999: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-a-port-in-Windows-Firewall
2. `java -jar hudson.war --httpPort=9999 --httpListenAddress=localhost`

You should now be able to access Hudson locally.

It sounds like 127.0.0.1 is not resolving as localhost.  Please check this:

```
notepad %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

You should see an uncommented entry of:
`127.0.0.1       localhost`

SoapBox: Please consider using Jenkins instead.  The vast majority of the developer base has moved from Hudson to Jenkins because of some heavy handed tactics by Oracle.